# Handling Height-Width vs. Width-Height coordinate order in PIL vs. ndarray

Tags: python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I am reading images with `Image.open()` and converting them into an `ndarray` using `np.asarray()`. I also need bounding boxes; for that I'm using `Image.getbbox()` when importing images and `ndarray.shape` later in the code.

I need to reconcile the usual Width-Height coordinate order of the images and the Height-Width order of arrays. Should I transpose the array after `np.asarray(image)` for preserving Width-Height ordering, or `asarray` takes care of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. The way `PIL` and `numpy` deals with images is different. Reason being that *PIL* uses column-major scheme for storing data, on the other hand *numpy* uses row-major.

So in order to create a column-major equivalent of the matrix in *numpy*, we have to swap the two dimensions.

```
img = Image.open(r"image_path")

arr = np.asarray(img)

arr = arr.transpose((1, 0, 2))
```

The above code transposes the dimensions of images having color channels > 1 (RGB, LA, PA, RGBA etc). If the image has a single channel (L, 1, I etc) then use:-

```
arr = arr.transpose((1, 0))
```

instead.

Comment: I think PIL actually uses *"row major"* storage.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually, It does **not**!!! Here's why. In order to understand why `PIL`  uses *column major* ordering scheme, we need to first know about orders, or how they are found. In imaging [***ordering***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) could be defined in layman's terms as *which axis is at the first index*. Where axis could be `x` (horizontal axis) or y (vertical axis). In imaging when we say an image is `(1920, 1080)` it means that the image contains 1920 columns and 1080 rows `(y, x)` (generally columns are more then the number of rows).

Comment: When we try to open a (1920, 1080) in PIL using `Image.open()` we get `Image.size` (1920, 1080). But when we try to open the same image using `numpy` or `cv2` (both use numpy arrays for storing image data) via `cv2.imread()` etc. and then find it's dimensions (using `shape`) we get (1080, 1920). This states that numpy uses row major. Why? Because the number of rows (1080 in this case) is at the first index.

Comment: The order of the indices tells you the *"access ordering"* which is not the same as the *"storage ordering"*. PIL/Pillow is based on its `C` core routines and `C` uses row major ordering. If you load a 4-column by 2-row image with known values and dump it using `Image.tobytes()` you will see that it gives you the pixels in the first row followed by the pixels in the second row, i.e. row major storage.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I won't put a string on your claim, as currently i am unaware of how is pixel data stored? So probably you would be right on that. What i was trying to convey via the means of this answer, is the fact that `numpy` and `PIL` uses different ordering scheme for accessing pixel data when opening images. Which results in swapped dimensions when transitioned from one library to the other.

Comment: If the answer contains any claim/content which you believe is incorrect, then feel free to rectify it ^_^